# Addition Base url in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I had added new base url in Drupal in setting.php but it is not accessible on another page..

```
$base_url  =   'http://'             //working
$base_url_theme = 'http://'           //not working
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The variable $base_url_theme isn't standard in settings.php, but if you tell us what you end goal is we can help you get there.

Answer (score 1):

You can get theme path like this:

```
$theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_machine_name');
```

And use that variable as previx of path to theme elements (images...).